# How long to find a Preimage in python

Tags: python, encryption

For 8 bit and 16 bit I am trying to find a preimage of the corresponding hashes "\00" and "\00"*2.

I have only very rudimentary python code and any help would be appreciated.

```
import hashlib  

preimage = bytes.fromhex('?')
bin(int(preimage.hex(), 8))
hashlib.sha256(preimage).hexdigest()
print(hashlib.sha256(preimage).hexdigest())
```

Comment: Not clear what you want and this is not a coding service. Here is what I've written for finding the [leading zeros for SHA1](https://github.com/kelalaka153/SHA-1-LeadingZeroes) for this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83227/18298). Those may help you.

Comment: How long does it take? Run it and measure the time it takes.